# Browser Shows cached copy of my html page

Tags: html, tomcat

I wrote an HTML page and hosted it in tomcat servers (wit other JSP pages). I changed something in the HTML page, but still it seems tomcat still serving the old cached html. even after many days now.

how could I instruct tomcat to use the newer modified html page.

Comment: Restart server, delete cache, refresh website ... that usually does the trick

Comment: How could I delete cache from tomcat?

Comment: Follow the steps for either windows or linux listed here: http://support.grouplink.net/ehelpdesk/kb/kbView.glml;jsessionid=3859FD08443F5421FDE110C70FB53053?kbId=161

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read somewhere to put some random string at stylesheet for example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?randomstring" type="text/css" />
```

So the browser will load the css again, but I do not know whether it will reload html content but you can try it. To generate random string you need PHP

Answer (score 2):

You can force the browser to hard refresh your web page, simply using JavaScript here like

```
location.reload(true); //If false, browser will use the cached info
```